# why I can't compile successfully with the following code?

Tags: java, exception, apache-poi

```
public class PoiSheetUtil{
    public Workbook mergeExcelFiles(Workbook book, Map<Integer,InputStream> inMap) throws IOException, 
    InvalidFormatException{
        inMap.forEach((k,v)->{
            Workbook b = WorkbookFactory.create(v);
           //omit copy sheet method
            copySheets(book.createSheet(),b.getSheetAt(k));
        });
        return book;
    }
}
```

I get an error on line 5 which say that "Unhandled exception IOException,InvalidFormatException"

Comment: IOException and InvalidFormatException are checked exceptions so you need to catch them and handle them somewhere(for example you can catch them in the the method that calls your method mergeExcelFiles() )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is context; the code that potentially throws the exception sits in the lambda:

```
inMap.forEach((k,v)->{
    Workbook b = WorkbookFactory.create(v);
    ...
});
```

and it's the lambda expression, that does not properly handle the exceptions in this case. Try

```
inMap.forEach((k,v)->{
    try {
        Workbook b = WorkbookFactory.create(v);
        ...
     } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException exc) {
         throw new RuntimeException(exc);
     }
  });
```

or use some other kind of iteration construct (e.g., an iterator based `for` statement) which can propagate the exception transparently:

```
for (var entry: inMap.entrySet()) {
     final var k = entry.getKey();
     final var v = entry.getValue();
     ...
}
```